# Database design with immutable data that's never referenced after initial insert

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-11

#### Background

Currently a single PostgreSQL machine with 32 GB memory. Inserted data is immutable.

The information I'm trying to model can be described in three tables, where Table #1 has a one-to-many relationship with Table #2, and Table #2 has a one-to-many relationship with Table #3.

For example, if Table #1 would be a `car` table, Table #2 could be a table describing the car's `wheels` and Table #3 could be a table describing the wheels' `screws`.

In JSON:

```
{ 
  "car" : {
     "id" : 1,
     "wheels" : [
       { 
          "id" : 1000,
          "dimension" : "17",
          "screws" : [
          {
            "id" : "sc1",
            "rust" : false
          }]  
       }, 
       {
          "id" : 1001,
          "dimension" : "17",
          "screws" : [
          {
            "id" : "sc2",
            "rust" : true
          }]  
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

Inserts populate the `car`, `wheels`, and `screws` table, along with a `timestamp`. These rows are *never modified or even referenced by other rows*, after insert. Only read.

Current DDL:

`car` table (Table #1):

```
id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

`wheel` table (Table #2):

```
id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
car_id BIGINT REFERENCES car(id)
dimension INTEGER NOT NULL
```

`screw` table (Table #3):

```
id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
wheel_id BIGINT REFERENCES wheel(id)
rust BOOLEAN NOT NULL
```

The most common queries use columns in Table #2 in their `WHERE` clause. They further filter using Table #3 columns. To follow the same example, a typical query would be to return all cars with 17" inch wheels with a screw are rusting.

There's no need for data older than a week, so being able to purge data easily would be good.

While the size of Table #1 and #2 are relatively small, Table #3 can fairly quickly grow beyond 1 TB. I suppose it'd be like a wheel each having a million screws.

#### Current solution

I am partitioning Table #3 using a hash on the Table #2 id (e.g. `wheel_id`) so that the host machine can store partitions in memory to make queries faster. Partitions size will be equal in size.

#### Problem

Using the solution, I can't easily remove data based on the `timestamp` in Table #1. Since Table #2 references Table #1, and Table #3 references Table #2, cascading deletes work. But I'd like to avoid the need for VACUUM.

Partitioning Table #1 on the `timestamp` will not work since PostgreSQL doesn't allow for tables to reference partitions.

#### Question

I feel like I am going about this problem in the wrong way, since I am not utilising the fact that the data is immutable, and that data that's inserted is never referenced outside of the relationships between that particular car, wheel and screws. Removing a row in Table #1 could safely also remove the referencing rows in Table #2 and #3.

Comment: I don't understand what "*I'd like to avoid the need for VACUUM*" has to do with cascading deletes - that sounds like a perfect solution to your problem. Btw: it would be better to show the actual DDL for your tables rather than some aggregated JSON that does not reflect the way you store the data in the tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name would it not be even better to just detach the partition entirely, without the need for VACUUM? I've added a DDL along with the JSON. I added the JSON to communicate what the data looks like as it's fed to my service. (The reason I'm using an example instead of the actual field names is because of business discretion.)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't understand you want to do the purging by detaching partitions. Btw: Postgres 12 _does_ allow foreign keys referencing a partitioned table as long as the partition key is part of the primary key (and thus the foreign keys)

Comment: is that a typo in table#3? Shouldn't it be wheel_id rather than car_id?

Comment: Thanks @TomC, you're correct. Fixed.